# How to set X-Requested-With header in AngularJS ngDialog plugin

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework2, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, ng-dialog

I was able to figure out how to get the $http object to send X-Requested-With header but I now need to do the same for AngularJS's ngDialog plugin. (or would prefer to)

I'm trying to use the Zend Framework 2 getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() to detect ajax calls in a controller, but that means I need to be able to set the X-Requested-With header to XMLHttpRequest

SW

Comment: You can change the [source](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/blob/master/js/ngDialog.js#L596) and add headers with `$http.defaults`. Otherwise I'm not sure if it's possible.